# What is a parity check matrix? (Information theory)

Tags: information-theory

I'm studying information theory but one thing I can't seem to work out.

I know that given a linear code C and a generator matrix M I can work out all the possible codewords of C.

However I do not understand:

- What a parity check matrix is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix
- How to make a parity check matrix from a generator matrix

I'd really appreciate any pointers!

Thanks!

Comment: You would appreciate pointers? http://xkcd.com/138/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your link explains it fairly well, but I'll try to simplify further.

Let *x* be your message, a *k*-element row vector. Let *G* be your generator matrix, an *k*-by-*n* binary matrix where *n* > *k*. Let *y* be your *n*-element transmitted codeword where *y* = *xG*. Let *z* be your *n*-element received codeword.

Hopefully, *z = y*. But when transmitting *y* across a noisy channel, it is possible for *y* to become corrupted, e.g., *z* != *y*.

An (*n-k*)-by-*n* parity matrix *H* is applied to the received codeword *z* to check if *z* is valid. The vector *w = zH'* can detect up to a certain number of bit errors in *z*.

Answer (score 2):

`In coding theory, a parity-check matrix of a linear block code C is a generator matrix of the dual code.` As such, a codeword c is in C if and only if the matrix-vector product `Hc=0`.

The rows of a parity check matrix are parity checks on the codewords of a code. That is, they show how linear combinations of certain digits of each codeword equal zero. For example, the parity check matrix

[image]

specifies that for each codeword, `digits 1 and 2 should sum to zero` (according to the second row) and `digits 3 and 4 should sum to zero`.

Answer (score 1):

LDPC i believe uses parity check matrix. more generally error control/correction algorithms